# Open and closed balls in $C[a,b]$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a non empty set and let $C[a,b]$ denote the set of all real or complex valued continuous functions on $X$ with a metric induced by the supremum norm.

How to find open and closed balls in $C[a,b]$? Can we see them geometrically? For example what is an open ball $B(x_0;1)$ i.e. ball centered at $x_0$ with radius $1$ in $C[a,b]$. I can visualize them in $\mathbb R^n$ but when it comes to functional spaces I have no clue how to identify them?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I assume $X$ is the interval $[a,b]$? Given a continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ I would visualize the open ball of radius one around $f$ to be the set of all functions whose graphs exist in the strip between the graphs of $y=f(x)+1$ and $y=f(x)-1$.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you should think of it just like you think of any other metric space. Every norm $\|\cdot\|$ induces a metric $d(x,y) := \|x-y\|$.

In your example,
$$ B(x_0, 1) = \{ f: X \to \mathbb R \Big \vert \|f - x_0\|_\infty < 1 \}$$

In the $\sup$-norm, these $f$ are all functions that are never further away from $x_0$ at any given $x$ in $\mathbb R$. This is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering but still i am not able to see it geometrically.

Comment: @srijan Does the picture help?

Comment: N  I am very much thankful to you. Now things are transparent.

Comment: Note also: the graphs of the functions inside the open/closed ball can intersect the black curve, and the boundary of the closed ball (the sphere) are those functions inside whose graphs *touch* (at least once) one of the two red curves that bound the strip.

Comment: @srijan Glad I could help : )

Comment: @anon Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

So I'm new here and sorry if I have this wrong, but apparently I'm not meant to respond to other answers; yet I also need 50 reputation to add a comment, so I can't do that? Anyway, I believe the above answers are incorrect. Just take the center of an open ball to be the zero function (radius 1) and $f$ to be $2/\pi \arctan(x)$. Then $f(x)$ is always within a distance of 1 from the center (strictly) in R, but $f$ is a distance of 1 from the zero function (exactually 1, so not in the open ball) in the function space, because the supremum of $\{f(x)-0 | x \in R\}$ is indeed 1. In fact f is on the boundry in the function space despite its values never touching 1 or -1 in R.

Comment: OP's question was specifically about $C[a,b]$ not $C(\mathbb R)$ which indeed behaves a bit differently.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ behaves differently because it isn't bounded; hence it isn't compact.  Since $[a,b]$ is compact, any function attains its supremum value somewhere on the interval, thus we won't run into this problem.

Comment: I agree with the comments give above.