# Showing a subset of $C([0,1])$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $${\cal F}=\left\{ f:\left[0,1\right]\to\mathbb{R} : \left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\right|\le\left|x-y\right|\mbox{ and }{\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx=1}\right\}.$$  Show that ${\cal F}$  is a compact subset of $C\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$.

When I am trying to show a set is compact, I usually resort to the every open cover has a finite subcover definition.  But if this case, we are dealing with functions.  So I am having a difficulty "visualizing" what's going on. Any help or solutions would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I should mention that we are working with respect to the sup norm.

Comment: What topology does $C([0,1])$ have? The uniform one? If yes, then work with sequences instead of covers. Try showing that any sequence has a uniformly convergent subsequence.

Comment: Have you seen the [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem)?

Comment: Yes we have seen it. Never thought of using it though!!

Comment: Perhaps it's not particularly usual for this question, but since you mentioned that you don't know how to visualize $C[0,1]$ with sup-norm, you might have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148349/open-and-closed-balls-in-ca-b).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Compact_metric_spaces_and_compact_Hausdorff_spaces) you only have to show that $\mathcal F$ is

- equicontinuous, i.e. $(\forall x\in[0,1])(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists \delta>0)(\forall f\in\mathcal F) (\forall y) |y-x|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$;
- pointwise bounded;
- closed in $C[0,1]$.

Both *equicontinuity* <s>and pointwise boundedness</s> follow from the Lipschitz condition $|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|$.

To show *pointwise boundedness* you can notice that $|f(x)-f(0)|\le |x|=x$, which means
$$f(0)-x \le f(x) \le f(0)+x.$$
If you apply integral $\int_0^1$ to the left inequality, you get $f(0)\le\int_0^1 (x+f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac32$. Now the right inequality implies
$f(x)\le \frac52$ for each $x$. 
(Thanks to [Nate Eldredge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153122/showing-a-subset-of-c0-1-is-compact/153130#comment352935_153130), who pointed in his [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153122/showing-a-subset-of-c0-1-is-compact/153130#comment352935_153130), that this was missing in my original answer.)

To show that it is *closed* in sup-norm, you only have to show that if $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly and $f_n\in\mathcal F$, then the limit is in $\mathcal F$. 
We know that integral behaves well w.r.t. uniform convergence, see [this questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24171/lebesgue-integral-uniform-convergence). Proof of the fact that the condition $(\forall x,y\in [0,1])|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|$ is preserved by uniform convergence is more-or-less standard. (In fact, in this part we only use pointwise convergence.)

Comment: Pointwise boundedness doesn't follow from Lipschitz alone.  The condition on the integrals will have to be used as well.

Comment: Thanks Nate, I hope the new version is correct.

Comment: @Galois: It would be a worthwhile and probably enlightening exercise *not* to use the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem and do the proof of (sequential) compactness of $\mathcal{F}$ by hand. If you're getting stuck, look at the proof of the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem and adapt it to the present situation.