# Arzelà-Ascoli for subset in $C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $M_c := \{f\in C^1([0,1]):\int |f|^2+\int |f'|^2\le c\}\subset C([0,1])$. Show that $\overline{{M}_c}$ is compact.

So since we are in a complete space, it is sufficient to show that $M_c$ is totally bounded, which means we need to verify equicontinuity and uniform boundedness. Equicontinuity is no problem, we get directly from the fundamental theorem and the Hölder inequality that $|f(y)-f(x)|\le |y-x|^\dfrac{1}{2}c$. Also we get from the definition $|f(x)-f(0)|\le c$, with which we can find that $f(0)\le c + \sqrt{c}$ such that $f(x)\le\sqrt{c} + 2c$ (analogous to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488145/arzel%C3%A1-ascoli-to-show-that-a-given-subset-of-ca-b-is-compact?noredirect=1&lq=1)). So we have a uniform upper bound for all $f$, but I don't see how one can arrive at a lower bound from that, which is needed for uniform boundedness.

Comment: Arguing more or less as above gives $|f(x)|\le k$ for some constant $k$, which is exactly what you need.

Comment: The point is, I dont see the argument that "is more or less as above", hence the question.

Comment: Look at it this way. If you've proved that $f(x)\le k$ for every $f\in M_c$ then it follows that $-f(x)\le k$ (and hence $f(x)\ge -k$), since $-f\in M_c$ if $f\in M_c$. That does what you need - it also shows that a proof that $f(x)\le k$ _could_ be modified to give a proof that $|f(x)|\le k$.

Comment: Sorry - yes, I missed the bar. It's easier to see now...

Comment: Thanks! I did not see that the set also contains $-f$, from which, as you said, the other bound follows analogously.

Answer (score 1):

Because the functions $f$ are absolutely continuous,
$$
                xf(x)  = \int_{0}^{x}(f+tf')dt \\
               (1-x)f(x)  = \int_{x}^{1}(-f+(1-t)f')dt \\
                  f(x)  = xf(x)+(1-x)f(x).
$$
These identities and $2|ab|\le |a|^2+|b|^2$ give a uniform estimate for $f$:
$$
   |f(x)| \le (\|f\|\|1\|+\|f'\|\|t\|)+(\|f\|\|1\|+\|f'\|\|1-t\|) \\
    \le (\|f\|^2+\|f'\|^2)+C \le c^2+C.
$$